# What is comparing in BinarySearch?

Tags: c#, list, search, comparison, binary-search

Sorry for question that seems to be easy, but I cannot find on internet this thing:

```
this.StorageComputers.BinarySearch(new StorageComputer(IPAddress.Any, Space), new StorageComputerComparer());
```

My problem is that I don't know, if they're comparing enumerated objects with first argument, or first argument with enumerated object. I'm looking for this because in BinarySearch I need to return that StorageComputer, whitch's free space is bigger than free space of first argument. Does anybody know, how can I make it? I know that I can search it via foreach loop of this.StorageComputers list, but I have ridden somewhere that BinarySearch is faster than normal search. Please help me.

**EDIT:**

Code was developed by me. I found answer on my question alone.

The first argument of method Compare is enumerated object, the second is the object specified in method BinarySearch as first argument.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you are not really trying to find the StorageComputer with a Space equivalent to your first argument, but instead are trying to find a computer with greater space?

Comment: Note that a binary search requires the list to be sorted in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at Microsoft's [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx).

`this.StorageComputers.BinarySearch(new StorageComputer(IPAddress.Any, Space), new StorageComputerComparer());` is an implementation of `List(T).BinarySearch(T, IComparer(Of T))`

`List(T)` can be `this.PotatoSalad` if I implemented it as such.

Comment: Right on top of the page: "Searches the entire sorted List(Of T) for an element using the specified comparer and returns the zero-based index of the element."

T is Storage Computers. See edited answer.....

Comment: I applaud you. Answer your own question and accept your own answer!